# using variable on pageload and modify if changed

Tags: php

i got this variable:

```
$machine=isset($_POST['machine'])?$_POST['machine']:'';
```

for my selectbox:

```
<select id="machine" name="machine">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
</select>
```

now i want to made some modifications. i have saved in my settings **$favmachine=4**.
for example i load the page with

```
if($favmachine!=0)
{
    $machine=$favmachine;
}
```

my form looks like this (exactly what i want):

```
<select id="machine" name="machine">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">D</option>
</select>
```

the problem now is when i want to change for example from D to A it goes to D again.. right exactly what i wrote... but i dont know how to handle this problem

i want my $favmachine selected on pageload (works) BUT want to be able to change it to another machine and set this to $machine by $_POST

hope you understand my problem :D

Comment: Did you wrote anything on onChange event for that select drop down? If you, then post that code please!

Comment: Do you have any other elements in the form with 'name="machine" ?

Comment: i just need a php solution.. its hard to explain..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to *overwrite* `$machine` with `$favmachine` *only* if the check for a POST value resulted in “nothing” before:

```
$machine=isset($_POST['machine'])?$_POST['machine']:'';
if($machine==='' && $favmachine!=0)
{
    $machine=$favmachine;
}
```

or in shorter form, using the `?` operator once more:

```
$machine = isset($_POST['machine']) ? 
             $_POST['machine']
           : 
             ( $favmachine != 0 ? $favmachine : '');
```

(Multiple lines and indentation for readability only.)

Comment: Exactly what i need! Had some problems to explain the situation :D Thank you very much!